# Google Chrome element remains :hover even when moved away from cursor

Tags: javascript, css, hover, chromium

You can try it yourself in this fiddle. When you move cursor to the green square, it changes color to red one. Try to click, but do not move mouse pointer. The square flies away, but remains red.

http://jsfiddle.net/Rq6Vt/

Any ideas, what could I do with this?

Comment: Optimization: `state = !state;`

Comment: in my chrome, it does change the colour on click

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In some browsers, `:hover` is only recomputed when the mouse is moved, in an effort to be more efficient.

There isn't much you can do about this, unfortunately, except taking matters into your own hands and using JavaScript to change the box's colour when the mouse enters it.

Comment: This will also happen on touch devices with iOS (not sure about Android), as they will apply the **:hover** state on the first click but never remove it.